# Detailed logging in azure storage account?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-storage-account

Every 70 minutes or so, something is downloading some hundred megabytes of data from one of my azure storage accounts. Is there any way to figure out what is the cause?

All the logs and statistics I've looked at only give me graphs like this: [image: graph]

which tells me *that* stuff has been downloaded, but not *what* or by *who*

Answer (score 2):

You can find this information by viewing [`Storage Analytics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) data especially the [`logging data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging) contained in `$logs` blob container in the storage account in question.

You can use `Microsoft Storage Explorer` or any other storage explorer to browse the contents of this blob container and download appropriate blob. The request you would want to look into is `GetBlob` (that's the request sent to Azure Storage for downloading blob).

Comment: This works for blobs, queues and tables, but I can't find file share logs anywhere?

Comment: You’re correct. Unfortunately logging is not available for File Service.